# Looping Requests in Postman (using POST Requests)

Tags: testing, post, postman

I have a data file with over 10,000 requests and I need it to loop through each test.

Example of text file:

```
text1~text2~text3
text1~text2~text3
etc.
```

My test script is:

```py
pm.test("Status code is 200", function ()
    {
        pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    }
);

if ((pm.response.json()[0].ResultCode)===-1)
{
    pm.test("ResultCode -1 Matched!", function ()
    { 
        pm.expect(pm.response.json()[0].ResultCode).to.equal(-1);
    });
}

if ((pm.response.json()[0].ResultCode)===-5)
{
    pm.test("ResultCode -5 Matched!", function ()
    { 
        pm.expect(pm.response.json()[0].ResultCode).to.equal(-5);
    });
}
```

So the first test works and the second test works, but it stops testing furthermore.

The is my output of the tests tab:

[image: Postman Result]

I know that it has tested all the requests, as the body shows all the results; i.e.:

```
[
   {
       "ResultCode": -1
   },
   {
       "ResultCode": -1
   },
   {
       "ResultCode": 200,
       ...
   },
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can use a `while` loop:

```
var i = 1;
while (i <=10)
{
    if ((pm.response.json()[i].ResultCode)===200)
    {
        pm.test("Line " + i +" ~ ResultCode 200 Matched!");
    }
i++;
}
```

This has worked perfectly.

Reference: [Javascript Tutorial](https://www.dofactory.com/tutorial/javascript-loops)